# K MEANS Big dataset

Tags: python, dataset, k-means

Can you please recommend me for a big dataset for k means?

It would be cool if it will integrate easily with python, but any thing will be good.

Comment: Please add some additional information to your question in order to elicit a better response and avoid being down voted.  In particular 1) how big is your dataset? 2) How many features do you have? 3) How many test cases do you have?  Have you searched for other sources for this information?  Simply googling "k-means clustering python" returns the result that most people will steer you towards initially: `mini-batch k-means` using `scikit-learn`.  If you need better parallel scalability then we can steer you toward another package based on the answer to 1,2, and 3.

Answer (score 1):

For the very first start I'd recoment synthetical data. Simple draw a K sets of random distributed numbers with different means and required dimensionality.
The big advantage is that you know the result clustering and you can easily verify the result. Also scaling the data is not problem.

Comment: Do *not* use synthetic data sets. You are avoiding all the challenges. If you generate the data using Gaussians, the methods will converge easily, and find good solutions; but that is not what real data is like.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I understand your objection. My only point was: **start** learning using 1) simple data sets where you 2) know the answers.